# Internet Explorer 10 in Nokia windows phone not responsive

Tags: internet-explorer, responsive-design, windows-phone-8, nokia

I have used Twitter bootstrap to make my web site responsive. everything works great but IE 10 in Nokia (Lumia 920) windows phone. I searched alot and everybody says if I add @media(max-width:480px){@-ms-viewport{width:320px;} ...} it would solve the problem but the problem still remains. It is not only for my site, but also all other sites. IE 10 in windows phone is not responsive at all. any idea thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your website?

Comment: Please look at this msdn page from your Windows Phone with IE 10  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj862343.aspx

Comment: Check this article out by @stowball, should put you on the right track http://mattstow.com/responsive-design-in-ie10-on-windows-phone-8.html

Comment: thanks, I have read it. Maybe I can solve the problem on my site. but the problem is it is almost impossible to use IE on a Windows Phone becuase it does not reflow the page to fit the window. regardless the website.

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen this post from Trent Walton? Wherein he talks about media queries and IE10 in WP8 - http://trentwalton.com/2013/01/16/windows-phone-8-viewport-fix/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I fixed it using this meta tags:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

better explained in here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template

cheers.